# How to join two models based on common field in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-table

I'm new to MVC. I've two different tables tblEmployee and tblDepartment in both the tables common field is department id. 
I want show  list of Departments and their employees in different tables.

This is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Department> departments = db.Departments.ToList();
            List<Employee> ep = new List<Employee>();
            var q = from depa in db.Departments
                    join emp in db.Employees
                    on depa.Id equals emp.DepartmentId

                    select new
                    {
                        Name = emp.Name

                    };

            ViewBag.Data = q;
            return View(departments);
        }
```

This is my view :

```
@model IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails.Models.Department>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)

        </td>
       </tr>
    <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th> 
            <th>
                Gender
            </th>
            <th>
                City
            </th>
        @foreach (var it in  ViewBag.Data)
        {
            <tr>            
             <td>
            @it

            </td>
            </tr>        
        }

    </tr>
</table><br/>
}
```

but I'm getting all the employees in each department table and the o/p also not clear.
please help me in this.

Comment: Your loop is just naively displaying all the employee rows every time. There's no filter on it. You'll have to check whether `it.DepartmentId == item.DepId` before deciding to display that row from the departments. BTW instead of putting employees in the viewbag, it would be good practice to create a class containing both lists as its properties, and use that class as the model for your view (a ViewModel, funnily enough)

Comment: You need to create a **View Model** which holds all the required properties that you want to show on the UI. And then change your query syntax to select this new View model datatypeby filling in all required values. Set your view to use the new Datatype

Comment: either that or maybe `db.Departments.Include("Employees").ToList()` will produce you a model whereby in the view you can do `@foreach (Employee emp in item.Employees)` in place of `@foreach (var it in  ViewBag.Data)`. And then you can remove the second query. That way each Department object contains a list of Employees who are within that department. EF will work this out for you based on the foreign keys in the database

Comment: its working ... you saved my life thanks a lot...@ADyson

Comment: @Suthar I just posted my second suggestion (which I think is better) as the answer, hopefully that's what you used. Could consider marking as accepted answer please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing you have got your relationships (foreign keys) defined in your database correctly, this should work:

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  List<Department> departments = db.Departments.Include("Employees").ToList();
  return View(departments):
}
```

In the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails.Models.Department>

<h2>Departments</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
       </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th> 
        <th>
            Gender
        </th>
        <th>
            City
        </th>
    </tr>
        @foreach (Employee emp in  item.Employees)
        {
            <tr>            
              <td>
                  @emp.Name
              </td>
            </tr>        
        }
</table>
<br />
}
```